# Subquery to pull out multiple images for multiple products

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's what the table look like:

[image]

I'm trying to do a subquery that will pull each image name out for each product.  The subquery I got is only pulling the first one out.  It may be that I've been looking at it too long or whatever, either way, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Select  c.field_id_33  AS email, o.order_id,c.field_id_76 AS pics, Group_concat(DISTINCT o.entry_id) AS Products,group_concat(DISTINCT t.title),(SELECT field_id_76 FROM finn_channel_data WHERE entry_id = o.entry_id), group_concat(DISTINCT t.url_title) from finn_cartthrob_order_items o  
LEFT JOIN finn_channel_data c
ON c.entry_id=o.order_id
LEFT JOIN finn_channel_titles t
ON o.entry_id=t.entry_id
GROUP BY email
```

Comment: Only showing us the returned data and the query executed only gives us so much to work with. Show us your table structure and you might get more help.

Comment: It's using expressionengine. the channel_data is the table that has pretty much everything in it.  I just basically need to loop through the concated products and pull the picture for each one.